Alternative Big Union Symbol?
Is there any package or command that lets me display the big union symbol like in the first image? I find the latex default one a little unsettling (Book is Introduction To Topology - Bert Mendelson)

Code used for second image: $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha}$

Welcome to TeX.SE.

thanks, a pleasure

If a smaller height is what you are searching: Maybe the \bigcup of MnSymbol. For more alternatives see The comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List  (usually available as symbols-a4.pdf or symbols-letter.pdf in your TeX installation).

I wouldn't use the same symbol for binary union and for the union operator (that Unicode calls n-ary, who knows why).
Anyway, that's not at all difficult.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtx}

\renewcommand{\bigcup}{\mathop{\cup}\nolimits}

\begin{document}

If the indexing set $I$ contains precisely two distinct indices,
then the union over $\alpha$ in $I$ of $A_{\alpha}$ is the same
as the union of two sets as defined in the previous section;
that is
\[
\bigcup_{\alpha\in\{i,j\}}A_{\alpha}=A_{i}\cup A_{j}
\]

\end{document}


Compare with the original (image from a preview of Google books)

You can get something more like the original.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\mathchardef\std@cup=\cup
\renewcommand{\cup}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\cup@@\relax}}
\newcommand{\cup@@}[2]{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.2}{$\m@th#1\std@cup$}}}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\bigcup}{\mathop{\cup}\nolimits}

\begin{document}

If the indexing set $I$ contains precisely two distinct indices,
then the union over $\alpha$ in $I$ of $A_{\alpha}$ is the same
as the union of two sets as defined in the previous section;
that is
\[
\bigcup_{\alpha\in\{i,j\}}A_{\alpha}=A_{i}\cup A_{j}
\]

\end{document}

